# Need help returning height of right-triangle given one angle as well as one length

Tags: java

What I have :

```
public static boolean treeHeight(double distance, double degree) { 
    double trueTreeHeight = (Math.tan(degree)) * (distance);

    if (distance > 0.0 && degree > 0.0)  { //Parameter
        System.out.println(trueTreeHeight);
        return true;
    }
    return  false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(treeHeight(2000, 30)); //2000 = distance or length, 30 = angle provided
}
```

However it prints -12810.66239329255 when I believe it should be 1154

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `Math.tan` method should be in radians according to [the corresponding documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#tan-double-). I am saying this because it seems like you are using degrees instead (because of the name of the variable, but also because 30 radians angle seems like unintended and finally because indeed the tangent of 30 degrees angle times 2000 gives the expected result of approximately 1154).

You can use [`Math.toRadians`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-) to convert the angle from degrees to radians, for convenience.

Note that the check for a positive angle should probably be done *before* the calculation.